# Random Survival Forests - How Do They Work?

Tags: machine-learning, survival, random-forest

Survival Analysis methods such as Random Survival Forests be used for modelling survival, for example:

- Student Dropout in Education, Disease Recurrence in Health Care, Project Success in Project Management, Customer Lifetime Value, Reliability, etc

After reading through a number of papers (e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.1645.pdf), I am unable to summarise concisely in what way a Random Survival
Forest differs from a Random Forest.

Is anyone able to please explain how a Random Survival Forest differs from a Random Forest (splitting criteria, etc.)?

Comment: CART output of a Leaf is scalar mean of elements on branch. Has nothing to do with survival.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is in the splitting rule used to pick the predictor cutpoints at the tree branches. For branch points in a random forest with a standard regression, you could find a cutpoint to minimize the residual sum of squares. For a survival model you use a splitting rule related to survival and compatible with censored survival times, for example choosing a outpoint to maximize the [log-rank test statistic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logrank_test). Page 8 of the paper you linked outlines 4 such splitting rules for survival forests.